# Checkboxes showing through modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a modal box that is placed on a page that includes a form with a checkbox. The issue is, when I open up the modal, everything works fine except, the checkbox is on top of the modal.

Here's the modal's JS:

```
<script>
    usr_ddown = "hidden";
    function lchr_usr_menu(){
        if(usr_ddown === "hidden"){
            document.getElementById("ur_menu_lchr").innerHTML = "&#x25B2;";
            $("#usr_dropdown").fadeIn(200);
            usr_ddown = "vis";
            return false;
                }
        if(usr_ddown === "vis"){
                    document.getElementById("ur_menu_lchr").innerHTML = "&#x25BC;";
            $("#usr_dropdown").fadeOut(200);
            usr_ddown = "hidden";
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

The HTML/CSS for the modal:

```
<div id="usr_dropdown" style="z-index 100;position: fixed; top:81px; left:0px; right: auto; background: #470047; padding: 10px; right:0px; height: 300px;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 5px #000000;-moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 5px #000000;box-shadow: 0 0px 5px #000000;opacity:0.9;filter:alpha(opacity=90);">
                <div style="text-align: right;position: absolute; bottom:5px;right:5px;">
                    [<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="lchr_usr_menu()">close</a>]
                </div>
            </div>
```

Now for the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="YT_vid" name="YT_vid" id="YT_vid" onclick="inc_yt_f()" />
```

For some reason, all the elements are behind the modal except for the checkbox, I ran a google search and didn't find much. What needs to be fixed?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Checkbox CSS:

```
  input[type=checkbox],
  input[type=radio] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  }
```

Comment: What browser? IE by any chance?

Comment: Is this Internet Exploder? If so you will need to perform some kind of horrible hack like iterating the dom and hiding each dropdown on the page if useragent indicates IE.

Comment: @geedubb Nope... oh wait, I think I found the solution, would this be it? The checkbox had a display of "relative" I removed that....

Comment: @fermionoid Could you supply a jsfiddle example?

Comment: @sємsєм I believe I have found the answer on my own after coming here, thanks for all the help, it works now!

Comment: I will post the answer when I am allowed to.

Answer (score 2):

Check out bgiframe plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/bgiframe

It works by providing an background iframe.